# Tinymce changes full html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to load a full html document into TinyMCE. I have been able to accomplish this however when I inspect the DOM I see that it is really not my full Document. The Body tag has been changed with the Body tag from TinyMCE and a couple of things are missing from the head tag.

I need my body tags classes as well as attributes to be there because I have functionality as well as styling scoping down from the body tag. Because my tag is not there my page is broken, and I don't have the option of changing the html document.

Why can't Tinymce use my document as is and add functionality to it?

Here is my initializer.

```
tinymce.init({
                selector: "textarea",
                menubar:false,
                statusbar: true,
                entity_encoding : "raw",
                plugins: ["paste fullpage image link textcolor"],
                paste_text_sticky : true,
                toolbar: "SAVE | RENAME | DELETE | WBW | SOURCE | forecolor | image | link ",
                height : 650,
                document_base_url: baseURL,
                file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
                    img_file_node = win.document.getElementById(field_name);
                    if(type=='image') {
                        htmlEditor.find('#my_form input').click();
                    }
                },
                setup : function(ed) {
                                        //adding buttons here
                                    }
   });
```

EDIT:

Here is a example of my html

```
<body class="myprod-class" data-product="myprod" data-template="spread-template">
    <section class="card">
        <figure class="informalfigure">...
```

But when I inspect the iframe that TinyMCE creates I see this

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body" onload="window.parent.tinymce.get('content').fire('load');" contenteditable="true" style="">             
     <section class="card">
       <figure class="informalfigure">
```

Comment: Have you tried to add " valid_elements : '*[*]' "

Comment: @Bene yes I tried that

Answer (score 1):

It was occuring due to iframe creation through Tinymce plugin.

Probably you can assign the classes and data-attributes to `<body>` within iframe using Javascript / JQuery.

Apply these changes in "oninit" callback of Tinymce as

```
function myCustomOnInit() {
        $('iframe').contents().find('body')
          .addClass("myprod-class");
          .attr({
            data-product:"myprod", 
            data-template:"spread-template"
           });
}

tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        oninit : myCustomOnInit
});
```

**Note:** oninit callback specifies a function to be executed when all editor instances have finished their initialization. This is much like the onload event of an HTML page.

Comment: I don't think I can do this, the loaded file could be anything and I don't know what the attributes and classes will be necessarily. It needs to be more dynamic

Comment: You should have some sort of checks, because the iframe creation is done dynamically. You need to modify the plugin code related to iframe creation.